# How to display occurence values in multidimensional array?

Tags: multidimensional-array

i have a problem to display a column of an array.
I have this code to calculate grades for my students: the $AvgV (average) works well.

```
    $AvgV=array();
    $Sum = 0;
    for ($j=1;$j<9;$j++){
        for ($k=1;$k<=$NumStudents;$k++){
            if (isset($TableGrades[$k][$j])) {
            $Sum = $Sum + $TableGrades[$k][$j];
                }

        print ("k $k -> j $j " . $TableGrades[$k][$j] . "<br> ");
            print ("<br>"); 

        }

        if ($Sum != 0) $AvgV[$j]=round($Sum/$NumGradesV[$j],1);
        else $AvgV[$j] = '-.-';

        $Sum = 0;

    }
```

When i do a print, i obtain this:

```
k1 -> j1 5.5
k2 -> j1 3
k3 -> j1 5.5
k4 -> j1 4.5
k5 -> j1 5
k6 -> j1 5.5
k7 -> j1 5.5
k8 -> j1 4
k9 -> j1 6
k10 -> j1 3
k11 -> j1 5.5
k12 -> j1 4
k13 -> j1 6
k14 -> j1 5.5
k15 -> j1 5.5
k16 -> j1 5.5
k17 -> j1 5
k1 -> j2 5.5
k2 -> j2 5
k3 -> j2 5.5
k4 -> j2 4.5
k5 -> j2 3.5 etc....
```

I would like to make some statistics, that is to know, for example, in column 2 how many students got the grades 4.5 or 3.5 or 5.5 that is to group the grades in a new array like this:
For example:

```
6    5.5    5    4    grades   etc....
2     3     2    1    students
```

This function works well:

```
function array_count_values_of($value, $TableauNotes) {
$counts = array_count_values($TableauNotes);
return $counts[$value];
}

$TableauNotes = array($TableauNotes[1][6], $TableauNotes[2][6], $TableauNotes[3][6],   $TableauNotes[4][6], $TableauNotes[5][6], $TableauNotes[6][6], $TableauNotes[7][6],  $TableauNotes[8][6], $TableauNotes[9][6], $TableauNotes[10][6], $TableauNotes[11][6], $TableauNotes[12][6], $TableauNotes[13][6], $TableauNotes[14][6], $TableauNotes[15][6], $TableauNotes[16][6], $TableauNotes[17][6]);
echo array_reduce($array, function ($v, $n) { return $v + ($n == 6); }, 0);
```

But i don't know how to call the function and put the result in a new array.
I hope that my description is good enough. Thanks very well for your help.

Comment: Do you want to save the result of the array_count_values_of() in a variable?

Comment: I like your code but array_count_values can count only string and integer and in the array there are numbers like 4.5 or 5.5 And i don't know if my call function is good. $TableauNotes = $TableGrades

Comment: There is a workaround for floats - See this site: agyuku.net/2010/12/array_count_values-for-float/ Is that what you are looking for? I can update my answer if it is.

Comment: Thank you Soule, i am sorry, i began to study php 1 month ago. I am not sure if my call function is right, can you tell me?

Comment: The array is like $TableGrades [$i][$j] . For example, i have table with different number of students, sometimes 15 students, sometimes 16 students, sometimes 12 students. My call function goes to 17 and i have a message error when i click on another table students. I would like to put the call function with a variable that takes care of the number of $k in the array. Thanks

Comment: Ah, we are cluttering up the comments. Would you mind shortening your answer so that you have only the VITAL information and your function so that I can understand it better? I think there is some unnecessary info in your question, thanks

Comment: How to count all duplicate grades in the columns and group them in a new array like i said above.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I understood, you want to save the result of your function array_count_values_of in a variable... so do:

```
$myarray = array_count_values_of($value, $TableauNotes);
```

That will store the output of your function in $myarray.

Feel free to comment if I understood your question wrong, Good luck!